# Is there any ignoring mechanism in PhpStorm similar to .gitignore

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any ignoring mechanism in PhpStorm similar to `.gitignore` to exclude indexing and inception on some files/folders? So I can share that file among the team and commit its changes?

(btw, I already know the possible GUI methods to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

1. `Mark directory as/Excluded` for folders. Information about excluded stuff is stored in `.idea/<project name>.iml` file
2. `Ignore files and folders` in `Settings/Editor/File types` - stored in [Webstorm configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)/options/filetypes.xml